# Providing Documentation for an Unix command?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, manpage

I made an Unix command called macmac2unix, which converts a Word file from Mac to Unix.

How can I provide documentation for my command?
I want to read about my command with man

```
$man macmac2unix
```

Comment: BTW--The name "mac2unix" is already in common use for a utility that changes line-ending characters on ordinary text files. Using that name may cause confusion...

Comment: I'd suggest changing the question to make it generic. The fact that you have "recreated" mac2unix is distracting from the point of how to create a man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [Perl's POD format](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlpod.html).  Despite the name, you can use it outside of Perl scripts, and the [pod2man](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pod2man.1.html) command ships with OS X.  It's a lot more sensible that troff.  Reminds me of Markdown.

Here's an [example pod document](http://code.google.com/p/ddribin/source/browse/trunk/nsurl/nsurl.pod) and the [conversion script](http://code.google.com/p/ddribin/source/browse/trunk/nsurl/pod2man.command).

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently use also **[DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/)** to provide Documentation for an Unix command.